# Why the length of the slice in http.Header returns 0?

Tags: dictionary, go

From the source code of net/http. The definition of `http.Header` is `map[string][]string`. Right?

But why `go run` below code, I get the result:

> 0
>
> 2

```
func main() {
    var header = make(http.Header)
    header.Add("hello", "world")
    header.Add("hello", "anotherworld")
    var t = []string {"a", "b"}
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", len(header["hello"]))
    fmt.Print(len(t))
}
```

Comment: If you're unsure about contents of your structures, try using the [`%#v`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printing) format string, which prints all values with names nicely. Example: [`fmt.Printf("%#v\n", header)`](http://play.golang.org/p/vZWWRiV_sQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you try

```
fmt.Println(header)
```

you'll notice that the key has been capitalized. This is actually noted in the documentation of net/http.

```
// HTTP defines that header names are case-insensitive.
// The request parser implements this by canonicalizing the
// name, making the first character and any characters
// following a hyphen uppercase and the rest lowercase.
```

This can be found in the comment on the field Header of type Request.

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

Comment should probably be moved though..

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the reference of [`http.Header`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header) and the code of [`Get`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/header.go?s=963:1001#L25):

> Get gets the first value associated with the given key. If there are no values associated with the key, Get returns "". To access multiple values of a key, access the map directly with CanonicalHeaderKey.

So it helps to use [`http.CanonicalHeaderKey`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CanonicalHeaderKey) instead of strings for keys.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    header := make(http.Header)
    var key = http.CanonicalHeaderKey("hello")

    header.Add(key, "world")
    header.Add(key, "anotherworld")

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", header)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", header.Get(key))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", header[key])
}
```

The output:

```
http.Header{"Hello":[]string{"world", "anotherworld"}}
"world"
[]string{"world", "anotherworld"}
```